# OCaml - Give a function of type (int -> int) -> int

Tags: function, types, functional-programming, arguments, ocaml

I'm completely lost on this. It was explained that functions are right justified so that `let add x y = x + y;;` has a function type of `int -> int -> int` or `int -> (int -> int)`.

I'm not sure how I'd define a function of type `(int -> int) -> int`. I was thinking I'd have the first argument be a function that passes in an `int` and returns an `int`. I've tried:

`let add = fun x y -> x + y` --- `int -> int -> int`

`let add = fun f x = (f x) + 3` --- `('a -> int) -> 'a -> int`

Comment: The type of `add` is normal: `f` can take anything as long as it returns an `int` to be able to perform the addition.  For example `add int_of_string "2"` is valid.  the compiler generates the most general type and there is nothing constraining the type of `x`.  That would be different if you wrote `let add f x = f(x+1) + 3`.

Comment: ChriS's final example works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
let eval (f: int -> int) :int = f 0
```

?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't learned this way of defining functions yet. Is there a way to do it without the colons?

Comment: The colons are for annotating the type of something, usually just useful for human readers. You can leave out the type annotations: `let eval f = f 0 + 0`

Answer (score 0):

```
fun x -> (x 1) + 1;;
- : (int -> int) -> int = <fun>
```

or

```
let foo f = (f 1) + 1;;
val foo : (int -> int) -> int = <fun>
```

it works like

```
foo (fun x -> x + 1);;
- : int = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is highly associated with the notion of `Currying`.

But before that, let me say that if you want to write a function that needs a parameter to be a function, you could declare a normal function, and just use its parameter like a function. No need to complicate it. See the ex:

```
let f x = x(10) + 10
```

Now comes the currying part. In OCaml, the parameters are semantically evaluated just one at a time, and after evaluating an argument, an anonymous function is returned. This is important because it lets you supply part of the arguments of a function, creating effectively a new function (which is called Partial Application).

In the example bellow, I use `+` as a function (parenthesis around an operator turn it to a normal function), to create an increment function. And apply it to the previous `f` function.

```
let incr = (+) 1
f incr
```

The code evaluates to `f incr = incr(10) + 10 = 21`

This [link](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2011sp/lectures/lec03-scope/scope.htm) has more information on the topic applied to OCaml.